# What is the relationship between linear algebra and matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am confused regarding relationship between linear algebra and matrices?

Which of following is correct?

Is matrices same as linear algebra?

or

Not completely same but major portion of linear algebra is matrices but there are also other things in Linear algebra besides matrices ?

Comment: Matrices are a tool that are useful for (certain parts of) linear algebra, but linear algebra is much, much larger than matrices.

Comment: Matrices are a computational device we use to understand linear maps in finite dimensional vector spaces. Linear algebra is the study of vector spaces and that includes situations where matrices don't make sense such as infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @Gonçalo uncountably infinite dimensions require additional care.

Answer (score 3):

Linear Algebra is the study of Linear maps on Finite dimensional vector spaces. Matrices encode important information of linear maps. “Finite dimensional” is written explicitly because matrices are only defined for linear maps on finite dimensional vector spaces.

To answer the question “which one of the following is correct?”, the first one is wrong. Linear Algebra is the name of a subject in Mathematics. Matrices are mathematical objects.

The second one is also **kind of** wrong. Many introductory Linear Algebra classes would have you believe that matrices make up the majority of Linear Algebra, that is not the case. The majority of Linear Algebra is made up by Linear maps. Since matrices act in a similar way to Linear maps, some choose to focus mostly on matrices. That is why I said that it is **kind of** wrong. It is not subjectively wrong as linear maps come first and matrices second.

This is a valid question to ask due to how badly introductory Linear Algebra classes are taught and how bad most(popular) online references of Linear Algebra are. If you’d like to learn Linear Algebra, the best books I can recommend are Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler and Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze.